# WHILE condition

Tags: php, while-loop, fgetcsv

```
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE)
```

I don't understand this part

> ($line = fgetcsv($file))

What exactly is it checking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not checking anything.

It is assigning an array to the variable `$line` using :

`$line = fgetcsv($file)`

and then later it is checking if the file handler has not reached the end of the file with :

`($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE`

Answer (score 1):

`($line = fgetcsv($file))` is not checking anything, `fgetcsv($file)` returns an array and `$line` is that array.

Thorough description of `fgetcsv`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php